# How do I express "<array-of-true-or-false> = <array> <= <scalar>" using Eigen 3?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, vmat

I am porting some **MATLAB** code to **C++** using the **Eigen 3** template library, and I am looking for a good mapping for this common **MATLAB** idiom:

```
K>> [1 2 3 4 5] <= 3

ans =

     1     1     1     0     0
```

So, compare an array and a scalar, returning an array of booleans that has the same shape.

I understand that Eigen's **Array** class has coefficient-wise comparison operators, but if I'm interpreting the docs correctly they only work with another array; not with scalar values.

Is there some option I've missed that will perform the comparison with a scalar? Or failing that, a nice idiomatic way to create an appropriately-shaped **Array** filled with the scalar value for the RHS of the expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With thanks to **ChriSopht_** from the `#eigen` IRC channel:

```
VectorXd compareMat = ...;
double cutoff = 3;
Matrix<bool, Dynamic, 1> result = compareMat.array() <= cutoff;
```

So, the trick is using `.array()` to get at coefficient-wise operators, and of course then getting the return type right…

Comment: If you don't want to deal with the return type and you're using C++11, you can always use `auto result = compareMat.array() <= cutoff;` as well.