# Comparison operators in Eigen C++: what is the output type?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have a vector V consisting some zero and non-zero entries. I would like to know what is the type of `I`, defined as follows:

```
auto I=V.array()>0;
```

For now, I always use `auto`, but I would prefer considering the right type before compilation. I have tried `VectorXd`, `VectorXi`, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `V.array()>0` is a boolean condition.  Aren't you just looking for `bool`?

Comment: @NathanOliver As far as I can tell `I` ought to be some sort of array of bool-like, rather than a single bool. Edit: I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15938229/1424875) that answers this question unambiguously, hence a dupe vote.

Comment: The output type is Eigen::Array<bool,int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>.